# A robust convex optimization problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider a function $ f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the map $f(x,\cdot)$ is convex, and $\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ the map $f(\cdot,y)$ is convex as well. We assume that $m<n$.

Given $y^1, ..., y^N \in \mathbb{R}^m$, and $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, consider the following convex optimization problem.

$$ \min_{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n } c^\top x \ \ \ \text{ sub. to: } \ f(x,y^i) \leq 0 \ \ \forall i \in [1,N] $$

Let $x^\star$ be its optimizer, supposed to be unique.

Notice that the above optimization problem is equivalent to the following one.

$$ \min_{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n } c^\top x \ \ \ \text{ sub. to: } \ f(x,y) \leq 0 \ \ \forall y \in \text{conv}( \{y^1, ..., y^N\} ) $$

We now say that $f(x,y^k) \leq 0$ is a "true" constraint if it "really matters", i.e.
any optimizer of the problem

$$ \min_{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n } c^\top x \ \ \ \text{ sub. to: } \ f(x,y^i) \leq 0 \ \ \forall i \in ([1,N]\setminus\{k\}), $$

which we denote by $x_{ \neg k }^\star$, is such that $c^\top x_{ \neg k }^\star < c^\top x^\star$.

What is the number of true constraints?

Answer (score 1):

In generality, the removal of $y^k$ alters the feasible region iff $\operatorname{conv}(\{y^i, i=1,\ldots,N\}) \ne \operatorname{conv}(\{y^i, i=1,\ldots,N, i \ne k\})$. It is easy to construct an example, where all $y_i$ are extremal points of their convex hull. Note that, however, this may not change the optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks. So let me update the question, saying that a true constraint is whenever the optimal value changes. Then it is not clear what happens if all $y^i$'s are extreme points of their convex hull, because, as you say, removing one of them may not change the optimal solution. So I guess the question is still open.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that by "true" constraints you are meaning "active" or "blocking" constraints, that is constraints such that $f(x^*,y^i)=0$.

Because, by convexity, if a constraint does not block -- i.e., $f(x^*,y^i)<0$ -- then removing it from the set of constraints does not change the optimum.

To count the blocking constraints is quite easy *a posteriori*, that is once you know the optimum. In facts, most software provides you the "Lagrange multipier" $\frac {\partial x^*} {\partial y^i}$ which are null exactly when they do block.

To count the blocking constraints *a priori*, before to compute the optimum is a $NP$ problem. Even simplifying the convex hull of constraints $\{x|\forall i, f(x,y^i)\le0\}$ is $NP$.

Maybe you can find something starting [there](http://www.mathematik.uni-wuerzburg.de/~kanzow/paper/ident.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The set of active constraints is only a superset of the set of "true" constraints. In other words, it is possible that removing one active constraint the optimal solution does not change.

Comment: Let me understand: you can remove a constraint :


(a) "globally" because it is outside the feasible region (that is $\forall j \not= i f(x,y^j)\le0 \implies f(x,y^i)\le0$). This is mathematically useless (because it does not change the topology of the feasible region), and computationaly hard.




(b) "locally" because near the optimum $f(x^*,y^i)\lt0$. In that case, reoptimizing without this constraint will lead to the same $x^*$. Such constraints are easy to find, but you need to know $x^*$.




What are your "true" constraints?

Comment: I do not understand why you argument about $x^\star$. I am interested in the cost. Can you see what is meant in the question?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question. So I asked for precision in an other answer (to be able to use markdown)

Answer (score 0):

What are you calling a "true" constraint? 
Suppose you want to minimize $c(x)=x^2$ under some sets of constraints:

1. $x\le1$ and $x\le2$, optimum $x^*=0$ [$f(x,y)=x-y, y_1=1, y_2=2$]. The second constraint is *redundant*, it can be eliminated because its a consequence of the first ($y_1 \lt y_2$).
2. $x\le1$, optimum $x^*=0$. [$f(x,y)=x-y, y_1=1$]. This constraint is *inactive*, it in not eliminated because of other constraints but because it is true near the optimum ($x^*\lt y_1$).
3. $x\lt-1$, optimum $x^*=-1$. [$f(x,y)=x-y, y_1=-1$]. This constraint is *active*, you cannot remove it without changing the optimum.

Type 3 is clearly a "true" constraint and type 1 clearly not. But what about type 2?